# "(" A B C ")" or A B C - match the balanced wrapper or none regexp

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

```
BEGIN A B C END | A B C
```

Above regexp is supposed to match either `BEGIN A B C END` or `A B C` without being surrounded by BEGIN and END. Assuming being after the A while using a named group like in `(?<ImAfterTheA>A)`, in Java you need to give the first A a different group name than the second A.

```
BEGIN (?<ImAfterTheA_1>A) B C END | (?<ImAfterTheA_2>A) B C
```

So...I want to shorten this and came up with:

```
BEGIN? A B C END?
```

But then again this would match `A B C` or `BEGIN A B C` or `A B C END` or `BEGIN A B C END`, matching effectively a bigger language than the one I intended.

Can I put it more concise without widening the language and thus avoiding two different group names for a matching group?

Comment: i really didn't understand your question.

Comment: This question makes almost no sense. Be more specific.

Comment: Your 2nd Regex is not doing what you think it should.

Comment: You mean, it should either have both BEGIN and END or neither? In that case, only the fiurst one will do.

Comment: Well, without a BEGIN there can be no END

Comment: You have no other choice than using the first way.

Comment: Using Java's regexp implementation, this is not possible to do with a single regexp without repeating the pattern for `ABC`. If you don't mind it, then see @Bohemian's answer. PCRE regexp implementation does have the conditional matching feature, but Java's does not.

Answer (score 0):

This regex does what I think you want:

```
(BEGIN A B C END)| ((?<!BEGIN) A B C (?!END))
```

This matches either with BEGIB and END at the ends *or* neither BEGIN or END at both ends. In other words, if one of the wrappers is present, both must be present.

- `BEGIN A B C END` match
- `foo A B C END` no match
- `BEGIN A B C foo` no match
- `foo A B C bar` match

Comment: How is that better than `(BEGIN A B C END)|(A B C)`?  More specifically (per op's request) how it *more concise*?

Comment: @Madbreaks it's better because it won't match `BEGIN A B C foo`

Comment: This is interesting. Is the left hand side necessary?

Comment: @panny yea it is necessary. For a moment I thought it wasn't, but it is.

Comment: @Bohemian just a second...this looks unbelievable.  Looks like your Genius did a great job :)

Comment: hm, that's sad. Btw...talking about genius [a ted talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/elizabeth_gilbert_on_genius.html)